# Conditional styling not working as intended

Tags: react-native, expo, conditional-rendering

Creating tabs always works well in React and this is working when opening in a browser, but the 'tabActive' styling is not removed when another tab gets clicked. 'tabActive' styling is getting applied onPress to other tabs, but none of them are getting removed afterwards.
This seems really unusual behaviour that I haven't experienced before. How can I fix this?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';
import FAB from './FAB';
// Import Tabs styles
import { Tabs } from '../Styles';

export default function Jobs({ navigation }) {

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("All Jobs");

  return (
    <>
      <Header screen="Jobs" />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={Tabs.container}>
          <ScrollView
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            bounces={false} // iOS
            overScrollMode="never" // Android
          >
            {["All Jobs", "Your Posted Jobs", "Active Jobs"].map((tabTitle) => (
              <Pressable
              key={tabTitle}
              style={activeTab == tabTitle ? styles.tabActive : styles.tab}
              onPress={() => setActiveTab(tabTitle)}
            >
                <Text style={Tabs.tabTxt}>{tabTitle}</Text>
              </Pressable>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
      <FAB navigation={navigation} />
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tabActive:{
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#dfdfdf',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    margin: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 2
},
tab:{
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'unset',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    margin: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 2
},
});
```

Imported styles:

```js
import { Dimensions } from "react-native"

let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

//Tabs
export const Tabs = {
    container: {
        width: screenWidth * 0.9,
        height: 70,
        marginHorizontal: screenWidth* 0.05,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
        borderRadius: 8,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        overflow: 'scroll'
    },
    tabActive:{
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#dfdfdf',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        margin: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 2
    },
    tab:{
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'unset',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        margin: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 2
    },
    tabTxt:{
        fontFamily: 'Satoshi',
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#071B26'
    }
}
```

I've tried rewriting the styling in multiple ways and even using functions to return styling, but nothing seems to be changing the outcome of the active style being removed. I have cleared the cache in Expo and again nothing has changed. I am using Expo Go on Apple 13 mini and have opening in IOS simulator and browser. Only the browser is giving me the expected behaviour.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Could you create an [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) so we can see the bug in action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes string comparison return unexpected results. i think it is better to use some function instead of ==
Here you have the code:

```
style={activeTab.localeCompare(tabTitle) === 0 ? styles.tabActive : styles.tab}
```

I hope that helps!

Edit!

Maybe you can try to change the background insted of unset it:

```
backgroundColor: '#fff',
```

or

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
```

Comment: Using `==` is a perfectly valid way to compare 2 strings (although I would suggest using `===`), there shouldn't be any reason `==` doesn't work in OPs case, especially as they are setting their state to one of the string values they're comparing against with `setActiveTab(tabTitle)`.

Comment: Maybe it's valid but if I have to do it I think it's better to use functions. And if you don't want to do that, a better solution will be to use some identification number instead of the tab title. Use texts with special characters to compare it is never a good idea.

Comment: There isn't a reason though why `.localCompare()` would make a difference here though. I created an [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@clapynick/deselect-style-not-working-example) and tested it, your second solution fixes the bug (`localCompare` doesn't change it though), nice spot (+1).

Comment: As i said, it's a preference i have. Thanks for the testing though!

Answer (score 2):

Amazingly setting the background from 'unset' to 'transparent' has fixed it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You should mark the other answer as “answered” (if it solved your issue) by clicking the grey checkmark.